# Access 2010 - Stop Linked Table Locking Back End DB

Tags: ms-access, locking

For simplicity I've created 2 accdb files, 1 called testBE and one called testFE.
testBE contains one table test. testFE contains one linked table to testBE-test. Both files are on my local hard drive.

How can I prevent the linked table in the front end from completely locking the BE DB? I've gone to options and set 'Default Open Mode' to 'Shared' and 'Default Record Locking' to 'No Locks' but if I open the linked table it creates a .laccdb file for the BE.

Comment: `if I open the linked table it creates a .laccdb file for the BE` -- That's what it's supposed to do.  Under normal conditions (i.e. using the table in an application), it won't lock the table, and it might not actually be locking the table anyway, even if you're opening the table directly.  The presence of an .laccdb file does not necessarily imply an exclusive lock on a table.

Comment: So it's not possible to make a change like adding a field to the BE table if the FE is open?

Comment: Not that kind of change, no.  Structural changes to the table requires exclusive access.

Comment: OK I suppose that makes sense really! Thanks for the info!

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you add that comment so I can mark it as answered?